# JavaScript date filtering issue

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code in js that needs to check the JSON based on today's date, and logging the results. Here is my code.

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    counseling_date: '2021-08-10',
    counseling_time: '11:30:00'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    counseling_date: '2021-08-06',
    counseling_time: '07:30:00'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    counseling_date: '2021-08-05',
    counseling_time: '16:30:00'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    counseling_date: '2021-08-02',
    counseling_time: '15:30:00'
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    counseling_date: '2021-07-26',
    counseling_time: '18:25:00'
  }
]

//Filter Data
data = filterArray(data)

//Filter data methiod
function filterArray(data) {
  data.filter(item =>
    console.log(
      convertToDateTime(item.counseling_date, item.counseling_time)
        .toLocaleString()
        .split(',')[0] +
        '\t' +
        new Date().toLocaleString().split(',')[0] +
        '\t' +
        (convertToDateTime(item.counseling_date, item.counseling_time)
          .toLocaleString()
          .split(',')[0] >=
          new Date().toLocaleString().split(',')[0])
    )
  )
}
//Convert date and time strings to date format
function convertToDateTime(cDate, cTime) {
  var custDate = cDate + ' ' + cTime
  var reggie = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/
  var dateArray = reggie.exec(custDate)
  return new Date(
    +dateArray[1],
    +dateArray[2] - 1,
    +dateArray[3],
    +dateArray[4],
    +dateArray[5],
    +dateArray[6]
  )
}
```

Here the entire code is working fine, but don't know why the last date is not satisfying the condition (though it is from last month). Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you are comparing two strings in this part of your code:

```js
(
  convertToDateTime(item.counseling_date, item.counseling_time)
          .toLocaleString().split(',')[0] >=
   new Date().toLocaleString().split(',')[0]
)
```

You need to be comparing them this way instead:

```js
(
  convertToDateTime(item.counseling_date, item.counseling_time).getTime() >=
  new Date().getTime()
)
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    counseling_date: '2021-08-10',
    counseling_time: '11:30:00'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    counseling_date: '2021-08-06',
    counseling_time: '07:30:00'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    counseling_date: '2021-08-05',
    counseling_time: '16:30:00'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    counseling_date: '2021-08-02',
    counseling_time: '15:30:00'
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    counseling_date: '2021-07-26',
    counseling_time: '18:25:00'
  }
]

//Filter Data
data = filterArray(data)

//Filter data methiod
function filterArray(data) {
  data.filter(item =>
    console.log(
      convertToDateTime(item.counseling_date, item.counseling_time)
        .toLocaleString()
        .split(',')[0] +
        '\t' +
        new Date().toLocaleString().split(',')[0] +
        '\t' +
        (convertToDateTime(
          item.counseling_date,
          item.counseling_time
        ).getTime() >=
          new Date().getTime())
    )
  )
}
//Convert date and time strings to date format
function convertToDateTime(cDate, cTime) {
  var custDate = cDate + ' ' + cTime
  var reggie = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/
  var dateArray = reggie.exec(custDate)
  return new Date(
    +dateArray[1],
    +dateArray[2] - 1,
    +dateArray[3],
    +dateArray[4],
    +dateArray[5],
    +dateArray[6]
  )
}
```

**Edit:**
To compare the date part only (Ignoring the time):

```js
convertToDateTime(
    item.counseling_date, item.counseling_time
    ).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)  >= new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this buddy. But a quick question, I think `getTime()` compares both date and time, I want. to compare only date.

Comment: Well, in this case, you can do `date.setHours(0,0,0,0)` for both dates before comparing the two dates, this will set both dates (hours, minutes, seconds) to the same values (0) to ignore them from your comparison.

Comment: Your code will look something like this:
`new Date(
  convertToDateTime(item.counseling_date, item.counseling_time).setHours(0, 0, 0)
).getTime() >= new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0)).getTime()`

Comment: Tried this. the `>` works but not `>=`. Any suggestions? here is a working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/5d6ebotz/

Comment: That's weird! Both seem to be working fine for me! can you tell me what output are you getting in both cases?

Comment: "11/08/2021 11/08/2021  false"
"06/08/2021 11/08/2021  false"
"05/08/2021 11/08/2021  false"
"02/08/2021 11/08/2021  false"
"26/07/2021 11/08/2021  false". I'm currently in IST. Also I've updated my input's first date to `11/08/2021`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235846/discussion-between-rakesh-and-abd-elbeltaji).